# $n$ degree polynomial $p(k)=\frac{k}{k+1}$ for integral $k=0$ to $n$.

Tags: polynomials

Here's the problem statement: Given an $n$ degree polynomial $p(k)$ such that:

$$p(k)=\frac{k}{k+1}$$

for all integer $k$ from $0$ to $n$, determine $p(n+1)$. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: There's always Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: For specific cases, like for n=3 or 4, I can determine the polynomial by determining p(0), p(1), p(2) till p(n). I get n+1 simultaneous equations which I solve to get the coefficients of the polynomial and then plug in (n+1). But it's too long and time consuming.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668108/115115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $P(n+1)=1$.

Indeed, consider $Q(X)=(X+1)P(X)-X$. We have $\deg Q\leq n+1$ and $Q(k)=0$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$. Thus, there is a constant $\lambda$ such that $Q(X)=\lambda\prod\limits_{k=0}^n(X-k)$.
To determine lambda, we note that $Q(-1)=1=\lambda(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!$, therefore
$$
XP(X+1)-X=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{k=0}^n(k-X)
$$
Substituting $X=n+1$ we get $P(n+1)=1$.